# Why is a homogeneous function called homogeneous?

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, terminology

Why is a homogeneous function called homogeneous?

When I ask this, I don't mean, "Show me how to algebraically manipulate a function whose input has been multiplied by a constant to get the original function multiplied by the same constant."

I mean--why do we use the word "homogeneous"? That word in particular must have been chosen for a reason; what is it meant to communicate in this context?

Comment: Note: the word is $\text{homogen}\color{red}{\text{e}}\text{ous}$.

Comment: For the curious: http://grammarist.com/usage/homogenous-homogeneous/
I'll update the post.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In a **homo**geneous polynomial, all terms have the **same** degree.

Comment: Holy crap? Is it that simple? Thank you!

Comment: @StudentsTea - If you are *fully* satisfied with this answer, please officially accept it.

Comment: Will do in time. Just giving other people time to answer / see if there isn't more for me to learn from this post.

Answer (score 0):

The function of one or several variables that satisfies the following condition: when all independent variables of a function are simultaneously multiplied by the same (arbitrary) factor, the value of the function is multiplied by some power of this factor. In algebraic terms, a function f(x, y, …, u) is said to be [homogeneous function](https://doublemath.com/homogeneous-function-definition/) of degree n if for all values of x, y, …, u and for any λ

f (λx, λy, …, λu) = λnf(x, y, …, u)

Comment: Hello, Azhar Ali! You have a great answer, but you should learn about equations. See here https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference